# Twitter API attribute to get when a person start following another person

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

it is  possible to get when a person start following a person in twitter using tweepy in python. which twitter API attribute can be used.

Comment: I believe it's not in the API, so no.

Comment: Is there anyway to do that.?

Comment: For your own user you can get it via UserStreams https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams , for multiple users via SiteStreams https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/sitestreams (closed beta). Using the REST API there is no way to get the follow event, you need to track the followed users and check for changes on your application to detect start/stop following events.

Comment: thank you Juan E. so I need to work on historical data of morethan one year, Do you know any twitter Dump that contain time which a person start fellowing another person.